# How is multiplication same as correlation

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation

In the following link, the summation of x*e is referred to as (in the following paragraph) correlation of the residuals and error term.

https://otexts.com/fpp3/regression-evaluation.html

I didn't quite understand how multiplication of 2 variables would be the correlation / covariance of the two variables. Can someone please explain. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correlation between two variables is their covariance divided by the product of their standard deviations. The sample covariance of two variables $X$ and $e$ is

$$\hat\sigma_{X,e}=(n-1)^{-1}\sum_i{(X_i-\bar{X})(e_i-\bar{e})}$$

When $\sum_i{e_i}=0$, then $\bar e = 0$, so

$$\begin{align}\hat\sigma_{X,e} &= (n-1)^{-1}\sum_i{(X_i-\bar{X})e_i}\\ &= (n-1)^{-1}\sum_i{(X_ie_i-\bar{X}e_i)}\\&=(n-1)^{-1}\left(\sum_i{X_ie_i}-\sum_i{\bar{X}e_i}\right)\\ &=(n-1)^{-1}\left(\sum_i{X_ie_i}-\bar{X}\sum_i{e_i}\right)\\ &=(n-1)^{-1}\sum_i{X_ie_i}\end{align}$$

This is why the correlation can be expressed as proportional to the sum of products of the variables. In general, when any variable is centered at zero, its correlation with another variable is proportional to the sum of the product of the two variables, even if the other one isn't centered.